# Webfont 'ubuntu' renders different offline compare to googleAPI

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, google-api

I want to use webfont "ubuntu" in my application:
When I used googleApi css url (mentioned below) it renders as expected:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But when I tried to generate the ubuntu font locally (to work the application offline) through "`http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator`", I am not getting the same results as googleApi css.
There is a minor difference in rendering some characters (e.g.: there is no hollow whitespace in the innercircle of @, a, g, etc..)
Kindly advice, how can I generate local font?